Is it possible to add a dismiss handler
I’m trying to run some code when a popoverTip is dismissed but I haven’t found a way to do it.
I tried popoverTip(tip).onDisappear { print(“tip dismissed”) } but that didn’t work.
Is it possible?
MRE:
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

struct MRETip: Tip {
    let title = Text("This is a tip")
}

struct MREView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .popoverTip(MRETip()).onDisappear(perform: {
                print("tip disappeared")
            })
    }
}

#Preview {
    MREView()
}


Please add a minimal example to demonstrate the issue.

@CouchDeveloper added MRE.

Note, that you can't use onAppear, onDisappear modifier after a "regular" popover modifier, since the popover modifier does not return the popover's content. You would instead apply the onAppear, onDisappear modifiers on the popover's content. However, the popoverTip's content is not a View, it's a Tip. It also seems,  popoverTip does not return the popover's content, akin the regular popover modifier. So, currently, I don't have an idea how to intercept onDisappear. You might consider to add action's explicitly and handle those in a way which solves your issue.

Additional note: it seems, the displaying rules for TipKit popovers are broken in iOS version 17.4. In my tests, once dismissed, the popover never shows again, despite all settings, rules and configurations tell that it should.  It works in 17.0 – as long as I understand how it should work. ;)

@CouchDeveloper thanks I thought also about using an action but that relies on the user actually using the action so it’s not 100% reliable since the user can dismiss with X button or tapping the background.

Exactly. Also, since there's no content view for the popup, we also can't use modifier interactiveDismissDisabled, which would alleviate some issues. Well, this is unfortunate.
